# Server-side event handler for TFS

Tags: tfs

I followed [the geekswithblogs tutorial](http://geekswithblogs.net/jakob/archive/2010/10/27/devleoping-and-debugging-server-side-event-handlers-in-tfs-2010.aspx), however when I check in an item, I get the following error on my event viewer:

Exception while attempting to inspect or instantiate type

> Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server.WindowsProvider in assembly C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\tfs\96d93be0\609f57b6\assembly\dl3\71c3ceb4\00f38a60_8f06cb01\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server.DLL: No parameterless constructor defined for this object.

What is the problem?

It looks like I don't even have the TFS server installed for some odd reason. That is probably the problem.

Comment: The link is (effectively) broken. It redirects to *[Geekswithblogs.net, the End of an Era](http://julian.farm/geekswithblogs/?url=/mtreadwell/archive/2004/06/06/6123.aspx)*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must have TFS server installed in order for the check-in to work.

Comment: I never knew that! Thanks obama!

Comment: What the heck you interesting character

Comment: My god! I'm a true character?! Really? Me? M_E? C_Haracter? With a capital C?